# pass parameters drush_make or drush_make_process

Tags: drush

I would like to call the following drush make command within drush script:

```
drush make someFile.make --no-core --contrib-destination=sites/all --yes
```

However, the Drush API for drush_make and drush_make_process only takes the directory name of the make file(thats how i uderstand, but may be wrong). So, i tried something like:

```
  drush_set_option('no-core',true);
  drush_set_option('contrib-destination','sites/all');
  $status = drush_make_process('.');
  //$status = drush_make_process('someFile.make');
```

This doesn't work. It appears that the make file is not even processed.  Any help i would much appreciate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most stable way to call Drush from a php script is to use `drush_invoke_process`.

For example:

```
$values = drush_invoke_process('@none', 'make', array('someFile.make'), array('no-core' => TRUE, 'contrib-destination' => 'sites/all', 'yes' => TRUE));
```

Comment: you should scrape all the drush answers you've given; tag them with a drush version number and put them up on an official drush FAQ somewhere :). Tips like this are hard to find I think. Thanks for your hard work on Drush Greg.

Comment: I used to do this, but haven't had time to update the FAQ in a long time.  Thanks for the thanks. :)

Comment: @tenken you could also upvote the answer to show your thanks ;)

Comment: Thank You Greg. This is my second you help me....you my hero!